# Passing values of latitude and longitude from ListViewActivity class to MyMapActivity class

Tags: android

I am having list of hotels in listview and their latitude and longitude.
Now I want to pass all these values to MyMapActivity class to display places of all hotels in the map.
I had retrieved all the value of latitude and longitude, but these are not retrived in the MyMapActivity class.

Comment: put it the in the intent as extras

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass latitude and longitude to getFromLocation method in Geocoder class:

Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
}
catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    locale = address.getCountryName();
    localenane = locale.replaceAll(" ", "_");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send latitude and longitudes to MyMapActivity class using extras like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyMapActivity class);
intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
startActivity(intent);
```